# email does not deliver body when I use < 'file'

Tags: linux, email, centos-6

Moving from centos 5 to 6.4.  I have many scripts that use mail with < 'file' at the end to email various reports to users rather than use -a BUT when I use that syntax with the mail installed on the new system the body is empty.
ex: mail -s 'subject' tfxobrien@gmail.com < /o/tob/file
works on old mail but not on new

Comment: Did you review the contents of `/var/log/maillog`? Also be aware that the default MTA in RHEL 5 was Sendmail while in RHEL 6 it is Postfix.